# The functors $h^n(X)=\text{Hom}(H_n(X),\Bbb Z)$ do not define a cohomology theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to show that the functors $h^n(X)=\text{Hom}(H_n(X),\Bbb Z)$ do not define a cohomology theory on CW complexes. If a contravariant functor $h^n(X)$ is a cohomology theory, by definition it must satisfy the followings:

(1) If $f,g:X\to Y$ are homotopic, then $f^*=g^*:h^n(Y)\to h^n(X)$.

(2) For a CW pair $(X,A)$, there is a long exact sequence of the form $$ \cdots  \to h^n(X,A)\to h^n(X)\to h^n(A)\to h^{n+1}(X,A)\to \cdots $$

(3) Excision holds.

For our definition of $h^n(X)$, (1) and (3) clearly hold, so I should show that (2) fails, and I think (2) should indeed fail because  $\text{Hom}(-,\Bbb Z)$ is not exact in general. But I can't find such an example for a pair $(X,A)$. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to find an example where $H^n(X)$ is in fact different from $\hom(H_n(X),\mathbb Z)$. The easiest example is, I think, $X = \mathbb RP^2$.

You can then take something like $A=S^1\subset \mathbb RP^2$ (corresponding to the nontrivial element in $\pi_1(\mathbb RP^2)$, which is what makes cohomology differ from the naive formula)

Then you have the long exact sequence in (usual) homology : $0\to H_2(X,A) \to H_1(A) \to H_1(X) \to H_1(X,A)\to H_0(A) \to H_0(X)$. The last map is an isomorphism, so we may change it to $0\to H_2(X,A) \to H_1(A) \to H_1(X) \to H_1(X,A)\to 0$

Moreover, $H_1(A)\to H_1(X)$ is the same map as $\pi_1(A)\to \pi_1(X)$ (both are abelian), so it's the usual projection $\mathbb{Z\to Z}/2$, so in particular it's surjective, so that $H_1(X,A)=0$. Finally, $H_2(X,A)=\mathbb Z$.

It follows that your long exact sequence looks something like $0\to \mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/2\to 0$.

So if you take $\hom(-,\mathbb Z)$ of it, you get $0\to 0\to \mathbb Z\overset{2}\to \mathbb Z\to 0$, which is *not* exact.

Comment: You are assuming the coboundary map $\delta: h^n(A) \to h^{n+1}(X/A)$ must be equal to the dual of $\partial: H_{n+1}(X/A) \to H_n(A)$. Strictly speaking, one may define these coboundary maps in some other way which would cause the LES in your example to actually be exact (at least hypothetically). See my answer below for a different example that demonstrates that no choice of $\delta$ will make $h^n$ a cohomology theory for all CW complexes.

Answer (score 1):

A fun answer using more machinery: Any cohomology theory that has the cohomology of a point the same as singular cohomology is isomorphic to singular cohomology. If $\operatorname{Hom}(H_n(-); \mathbb{Z})$ were a cohomology theory, it must then be isomorphic to singular cohomology. However, we know spaces such as $\mathbb{R}P^2$ where they disagree which yields a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, Hatcher is asking us to show that the functors $h^n(X) = \text{Hom}(H_n(X), \mathbb Z)$ cannot be extended to a cohomology theory for *any* choice of natural coboundary maps $\delta: h^n(A) \to h^{n+1}(X/A)$. In particular $\delta$ need not be $\partial^*: \text{Hom}(H_n(A), \mathbb Z) \to \text{Hom}(H_{n+1}(X/A), \mathbb Z)$. So simply showing that the long exact sequence of $H_n$ does not dualize to an exact sequence is not enough to prove that $h^n$ cannot be a cohomology theory.

However, two of the three maps in the long exact sequence of cohomology *are* prescribed by the functors $h^n$, namely
$$
h^n(X/A) \xrightarrow{q^*} h^n(X) \xrightarrow{i^*} h^n(A)
$$

If we can show that the long exact sequence of $h^n$ cannot possibly be exact regardless of the map $\delta$ by using these maps then we will be done. To this end, consider the pair $(S^1, M)$, where $M$ is the Möbius band and $S^1$ is its boundary circle. This is a CW pair. Its quotient $M/S^1$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb RP^2$, and in $H_n$, part of the exact sequence is

$$
H_2(\mathbb RP^2) \to H_1(S^1) \to H_1(M) \to H_1(\mathbb RP^2) \\
0 \to \mathbb Z \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_2
$$

Applying the functor $\text{Hom}(-, \mathbb Z)$, and introducing the a priori unknown map $\delta$, yields the (definitely inexact!) sequence

$$
0 \xleftarrow{\delta} \mathbb Z \xleftarrow{2} \mathbb Z \leftarrow 0
$$

So $h^n$ is not a cohomology theory, regardless of how $\delta$ may be defined, as claimed.